# Как избавиться от каскада switch case

Tags: javascript, рефакторинг

Есть викторина. В ней пользователь угадывает один из 3-х вариантов. Каждый вариант имеет свой вес:

- Вариант 1: 20 очков
- Вариант 2: 30 очков
- Вариант 3: 50 очков

Если игрок отгадывает вариант, то получает весь вес. Если нет, то только его часть, распределение которой строго регламентировано.

```
 Ответ игрока || Правильный ответ || Очки
      1                 1            100%
      2                 1            75%
      3                 1            50%
      1                 2            75%
      2                 2            100%
      3                 2            75%
      1                 3            25%
      2                 3            50%
      3                 3            100%
```

Можно запросто написать что-нибудь в духе:

```
calcRateScore: function(fact, user) {

    var rateScore = 0;

    switch (fact) {
        case 1:
            switch (user) {
                case 1:
                    rateScore = 20;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    rateScore = 20 * 0.75;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    rateScore = 20 * 0.5;
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            switch (user) {
                case 1:
                    rateScore = 30 * 0.75;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    rateScore = 30;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    rateScore = 30 * 0.75;
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            switch (user) {
                case 1:
                    rateScore = 50 * 0.25;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    rateScore = 50 * 0.5;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    rateScore = 50;
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }

    return rateScore;
}
```

Но выглядит это просто ужасно. Подскажите, как избавиться от этих `switch` / `case` (желательно от всех)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var answers = [
  null,
  {
    weight: 20,
    fractions: [0, 1, 0.75, 0.5]
  },
  {
    weight: 30,
    fractions: [0, 0.75, 1, 0.75]
  },
  {
    weight: 50,
    fractions: [0, 0.25, 0.5, 1]
  }
];

calcRateScore: function(fact, user) {

  var rateScore = 0;

  if (answers[fact] && answers[fact].fractions[user]) {
    rateScore = answers[fact].weight * answers[fact].fractions[user];
  }

  return rateScore;
}
```